# What sort of polarisation causes this effect

Tags: polarization

By some chance I acquired a pair of specialized '3d' glasses to be used in conjunction with a poster, such that when viewing the poster (which was a map of australia) the contours popped in and out of the page (seemingly). I was messing about and I looked at my phone's torchlight through the glasses, and was astonished, the light appeared like a horizontal beam of light, or a laser.

[image: here]

I believe this occurs however because the light was a 'point source'. Observing my computer screen with these glasses, apart from giving me a headache, seems to cause any image to have multiple 'shadow images' to the left and right of the main image, with diminishing intensity. Frankly, I have 0 clue how this comes about. Is it an effect of polarisation?

Comment: I guess the glasses might have sort of [lenticular plastic](https://www.google.ru/search?q=lenticular+plastic&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=isch&imgil=mY2qvJ_Q4iFPwM%253A%253BE2GBq6Q24mjVlM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.lenticular.mobi%25252Fwhat-is-lenticular.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=mY2qvJ_Q4iFPwM%253A%252CE2GBq6Q24mjVlM%252C_&usg=__i1zkw873XwwF_r_yxXm5esxOgbY%3D&biw=1280&bih=911) "windows".

Answer (score 0):

This might be different from what you have, but I have seen this effect on diffraction grating glasses. The shadow images that I see are because different wavelengths are bent at different angles by the diffraction grating. Because of this, on a computer I get major red, blue and green images, with some minor images further away from the centre.

Fluorescent lights also give interesting images, broken into colour components according to the phosphors that the light uses. Incandescent lights produce black body radiation (from heating a filament) in a continuum, so look like a stretched out line. If your glasses are diffraction gratings, it may be that your phone light produces a good approximation of black body radiation, but that would be unusual, leading me to think that your glasses may be different from mine.